# Deleting subsets in the list of sets

Tags: computational-mathematics, gap

If we have a list like $[[2,1],[5,2,1],[6,5,2,1],[9,10]]$ and I want to find the result in the form of $[[6,5,2,1], [9,10]]$ and want to delete all those list that are contained in another. How may I program this

I do like let FV := $[[2,1],[5,2,1],[6,5,2,1],[9,10]]$;

```
Intersection:=function(FV)
  local A, B, a;
  for A in FV do
    for B in FV do
      if Intersection(A,B) = B then
        a := Position(FV,B);
        Unbind(FV[a]);
      fi;
    od;
  od;
  return FV;
end;
```

However, I find the empty list after running this program. I need the answer like $[[6,5,2,1],[9,10]]$

Comment: I'm not familiar with the computer language, but maybe it should include the condition that A and B are not at the same position in the list  before the test for containment. If you run a check for whether A contained in B, and it happens they are at the same position in the big list of sets, then you don't want to delete that term.

Comment: @coffeemath: I think you're right. Also, `IsSubset` is a useful GAP function here. Moreover, use an index variable to index elements of `FV` instead of calling `Position` - using the latter one will be more expensive.

Comment: @smaz: could you please think of a better title - "Find Intersection of the List" does not correspond to what you are asking.

Comment: @Alexander is that mean that I need to make one more condition in if that B<>A or B is Subset if A then it will do compilation?

Comment: @smaz: you're welcome to try and see. I'd write a loop for `i` in `[1..n]`, where `n` is the length of the list `l`, to check for every element `l[i]` that it is not a subset of all other elements, and place all such elements in the new list instead of unbinding.

Comment: @smaz: "Intersection of the Collection of Lists" is not good either - you're not going to find an intersection of all elements of `FV` at all!

Comment: To restate what coffeemath was saying, because $A = B \rightarrow A \subseteq B$, you end up deleting everything.  You want to say "if $A \cap B = B \quad \land \quad A \ne B$ then ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved as follows:

```
smaz_Intersection:=function(FV)
  return Filtered(FV,L->not ForAny(FV,M->M<>L and IsSubset(M,L)));
end;;
```

In the running example:

```
gap> A:=[[2,1],[5,2,1],[6,5,2,1],[9,10]];;
gap> smaz_Intersection(A);
[ [ 6, 5, 2, 1 ], [ 9, 10 ] ]
```

---

Note: `Intersection` is a poor choice of function name: GAP already has an `Intersection` function and your `Intersection` function looks like it's intending to use GAP's `Intersection` function.  This might have some unpredictable results.

Comment: FYI, this was cross-posted in the GAP Forum with the following reply: http://mail.gap-system.org/pipermail/forum/2014/004532.html

Comment: In relation to that, `M -> not IsEqualSet(M,L) and IsSubset(M,L)` would be more robust since it does not require `M` and `L` to be sorted.